# How to calculate difference in number of days with the previous valid data row under the same group, without using multiple loops?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, apply, difftime

I would like to calculate the difference in number of days between each response with the previous valid row under the same person/name.

A set of simplified data is as such:

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                   Name = c("Jane", rep("May", 3), "Jane", "May"),
                   `Date Received` = as.POSIXct(c("2018-04-30 00:32", "2018-05-01 18:17",
                                       "2018-06-23 17:12", "2018-07-12 10:17",
                                       "2018-08-02 19:30", "2018-08-17 15:41")))

# ID   Name   `Date Received`
   1   Jane    2018-04-30 00:32
   2   May     2018-05-01 18:17
   3   May     2018-06-23 17:12
   4   May     2018-07-12 10:17
   5   Jane    2018-08-02 19:30
   6   May     2018-08-17 15:41
```

And this is the result I would like to achieve:

```
# ID   Name   `Date Received`     Difference    Valid
   1   Jane    2018-04-30 00:32   NA             Y
   2   May     2018-05-01 18:17   NA             Y
   3   May     2018-06-23 17:12   53             N
   4   May     2018-07-12 10:17   72             Y
   5   Jane    2018-08-02 19:30   95             Y
   6   May     2018-08-17 15:41   37             N
```

The first response received from the sender is always valid. A response is identified as invalid, and subsequently ignored, if it's received within 60 days of the previous valid response sent by the same sender.

The calculation of the time differences for responses received from Jane is straight-forward as there are only a total of 2 responses.

The calculation for May, however, is complicated. Since the difference for response #3 is 53 days (2018-05-01 to 2018-06-23), it will be marked as invalid. Therefore, to calculate the time difference for response #4, it is compared with response #2 instead of response #3 as response #2 is the previous valid data. As the time difference for response #4 is calculated to be 72 days (2018-05-01 to 2018-07-12), it is also marked as a valid response. Hence, to calculate the time difference for response #6 (2018-07-12 to 2018-08-17), it is compared with response #4, which is the previous valid data, and so on.

I have looked at some similar questions on calculating time differences, but they are either between adjacent rows or with the first observation in the group.

This the code I have currently which calculates the difference with the first response received from the sender (which is the incorrect method), and I have no idea how to continue from here.

```
data %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(Difference = difftime(`Date Received`, head(`Date Received`, 1), units = "days"))
```

Can someone please advice me on the solution to this question, please?

Thank you so much!

===========================================================================
Edited on 10/05/2019

I have come up with a solution for each group/person using for loop, using May as an example:

```
name <- "May"

dates <- data %>%
  filter(Name == name) %>%
  pull(Date.Received)

diff <- NA_integer_
valid <- "Y"

for (i in 2:length(dates)) {
  day <- dates[i]
  valid_dates_pos <- tail(which(valid == "Y"), 1)
  recent_valid_day <- dates[valid_dates_pos]
  diff_days <- ceiling(as.numeric(difftime(day, recent_valid_day, units = "days")))
  diff <- c(diff, diff_days)
  valid <- c(valid, ifelse(diff_days <= 60, "N", "Y"))
}
```

However, I would like to avoid using nested loops.

How can I apply this simultaneously for every group/person in a more efficient manner?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
n_vars <- 50
id <- seq(from=1,to=n_vars)
name <- sample(c("n1","n2","n3"),size=n_vars,replace=TRUE)
dte <- sample(seq(as.Date('2018/01/01'), as.Date('2019/01/01'), by="day"), size=n_vars)

data <- data.frame(id,name,dte) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  arrange(name,dte) %>% 
  mutate(
    diff=dte-lag(dte),
    valid=ifelse(diff<60,"Y","N")
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for the attempt, but unfortunately this is not the solution I'm looking for. My question is not merely about calculating the difference with the previous row (lag = 1). It needs to search for the most recent valid response (Valid == "Y") received before each observation to calculate the difference. Also, Valid == "Y" when the difference > 60, you have gotten it the other way round.